# Page level state in a TagHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have a tag helper that will be used several times in a page.  It outputs a script tag, but I only want this output once.

If there any mechanism for storing some state over the whole page rendering so I can test is this script has already been written?

`void Init(TagHelperContext)` is called on every fresh tag but the `TagHelperContext` is local to the rendering of this particular tree of tags.